# RoboCopy failed but without error messages

Tags: powershell, robocopy

My RoboCopy sometimes fails however it shows no error messages.

[image]

What I am doing:
Right now I am trying to robocopy between 4 folders. This is all done in a powershell script.

```
Robocopy source1 source2

Robocopy source2 dest
```

I, therefore suspect that the problem has something to do with open files, however, I have tried to implement start-process -wait and this does not help either. Have any1 had this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see the values under heading `FAILED` ??

Comment: As you can see in the image is says there are some files that fail, but i have no way to know why?

Comment: Then add switch `/log:<logfile>` to the command and check that afterwards